# How to lock a select query in Django so that other workers in celery wont access that record?

Tags: django, postgresql, celery

I have a table with lots of entries to process. we are using celery to run the background tasks. There are chances of processing same record by the celery worker. What can we do to stop fetching a record which is in processing state. we are doing background jobs for processing images from the table.

Comment: it's a rare sight to have a question and 2 full answers, a comment, on a low resolution, without scrolling

Answer (score 0):

I think creation task for every record in db should do the trick.
And the tasks are being delivered by message broker, so you won't loose any.